# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error swift xcode 8

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, xcode8

Good morning, I tried to select images from iOS photos library and also add to my custom tableview as UIImage. To do this job I wrote this code

```
func addPicture()
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        let p = Photo(Street: stationName,Name: "photo \(PhotosArray.count + 1)",photo:image)
        PhotosArray.append(p)
        print("le nombre d'images est \(PhotosArray.count)")
        TablePhotos.reloadData()
    }
    else
    {
        print("erreur'")
        return
    }
}
```

this is the code to the tableview

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return PhotosArray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.photo = PhotosArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

this is the code of the custom cell

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var StationImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UILabel!
    var photo : Photo?
        {
        didSet{
            updatecell()
        }
    }
    func updatecell(){
        Name.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleSubheadline)
        StationImage.image = photo?.myphoto
        Name.text = photo?.Name
    }
}
```

but sadly I got this error in execution **Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error**
I read many solutions proposed in Stack like editing the attribut Info in the function ***didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo*** to `Any` but nothing changed. I also modified the propriety Editing of `UIImagePickerController()` to true.
Can you please help me??

Comment: any idea please

Comment: On which line you are getting `error`?

Comment: there is no error in the execution i get this message .the app don'tcrash but the tableview don't add the selected photo

Comment: Is there a problem with your app besides the message?

Comment: No problem only this message in the debug console. i tried to add a breakpoint in these lines  if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage but i get nothing

Comment: have you set `imagePicker = self` anywhere?

Comment: non only in the viewdidload () i changed the property imagePicker.allowsEditing  = true

Comment: try moving `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated` to the end of the `if`

Comment: if you are allowing the image to be modified, you should also use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

Comment: i changed to UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage but i get the same message "Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error"

Comment: @Nathaniel i changed but nothing changed

Comment: @WalidSassi Did you try moving `picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated` to after you add the new `Photo` to `PhotosArray` ?

Comment: @Nathaniel yes i tried

Comment: What does the `Photo.init()` look like? Class or Struct? What is the `photo` property type?

Comment: class Photo
{
...................
    init(Street :String, Name:String, photo:UIImage)
    {
        _StreetName = Street
        _Name = Name
        _myphoto = photo
    }

    
    
}

Comment: FYI you can use ` (grave accent) on both sides of text to indicate it is `code` :)

Comment: If it's entering the `let` then the cast to UIImage must be ok. something might be wrong with the way you are displaying the image. Can you edit your question to show the `PhotosArray` and where you use the image for the `UITableView`?

Comment: 'class Photo
{
...................
    init(Street :String, Name:String, photo:UIImage)
    {
        _StreetName = Street
        _Name = Name
        _myphoto = photo
    }    
}'

Comment: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/art_greenberg1_sixtips1/elementLinks/thgreenberg1_fig08.jpg

Comment: @Nathaniel i changed the code below

Comment: maybe try unwrapping the photo with `guard let cellPhoto = photo?.myphoto`...  is `photo?.Name` showing properly? BTW, parameters are supposed to start with a lowercase letter

Comment: i added guard let but nothing changed!!! i used the version 2.3 legacy of swift  and xcode 8.0 version maybe the pb is from the swift version or xcode